# Center a text above and under an arrow in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a flow diagram and I am having some trouble getting the details right. For now, my code looks like this:

```
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!40, 
    text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \draw ++(0,0) node [block] (signal) {Señal temporal};
    \draw ++(4,0) node [block] (FFT)  {Transformada rápida de Fourier};
    \draw ++(9,0) node [block] (MSF)  {Mapeo a escala de Mel};
    \draw ++(13.5,-1.5) node [block] (Log)  {Logaritmo de la potencia};
    \draw ++(9,-3) node [block] (DCT) {Transformada Coseno Discreta};
    \draw ++(4,-3) node [block] (MFCC) {Descriptores MFCC};

    % Draw edges
    \path [arrow] (signal) -- (FFT);
    \path [arrow] (FFT) -- node {espectro} (MSF) ;
    \draw[arrow] (MSF.east) -- node [above] {espectro} node [below] {de Mel} ++(1.5,0)   -|  (Log.north);    
    \draw[arrow] (Log.south) --  ++(0,-0.86)   --  (DCT.east);    
    \path [arrow] (DCT) -- (MFCC) ;
    
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[MFCC]{Diagrama en bloques del cálculo de las MFCC para un frame.}
\label{MFCC}
\end{figure}
```

Which outputs this:

[image: How my tikz picture looks like]

In the first line, all the way up to the right there is a text above and under the arrow "espectro de Mel" I would like this to be centered to the right like this:

[image: What I would like to accomplish]

Of course, I can accomplish this easily with an image editor but I think this can by done with code.

Thank you for your answers, and I will gladly receive any suggestions regarding the rest of the image as well.

Comment: `[above,midway]` comes to mind ;-)

Comment: That seems so simple it should work but it doesn´t. I also don´t get any warnings or errors, just the exact same output :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some comments:

- `tikzset{stylename/.style={}}` is  recommended over `\tikzstyle`.
- Nodes are positioned relative to each other, using the syntax of the `positioning` library.
- The right-down line is drawn with `(node1) -| (node2)`, and in this case `pos=0.25` will be halfway between the first node and the corner.

  In your original code you have `(MSF.east) -- <nodes are here>  ++(1.5,0)   -|  (Log.north)`, so the nodes are placed halfway between the right edge of `MSF` and a point `1.5` units right of `MSF`. Then the line continues horizontally until it reaches the x-coordinate of `Log.north`, where it turns and goes down to `Log`.
- While it still works, the `arrows` library is deprecated in favour of `arrows.meta`. Making that switch requires a small change in the specification of the arrow tip.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
     block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=red!40, text width=6em,
                   text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em},
     arrow/.style={-{Stealth[]}}
     }
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block] (signal) {Señal temporal};
    \node [block,right=of signal] (FFT)  {Transformada rápida de Fourier};
    \node [block,right=2cm of FFT] (MSF)  {Mapeo a escala de Mel};
    \node [block,below right=0.2cm and 1cm of MSF] (Log)  {Logaritmo de la potencia};
    \node [block,below left=0.2cm and 1cm of Log] (DCT) {Transformada Coseno Discreta};
    \node [block,left=2cm of DCT] (MFCC) {Descriptores MFCC};


    % Draw edges
    \draw [arrow] (signal) -- (FFT);
    \draw [arrow] (FFT) -- node [above] {espectro} (MSF);
    \draw[arrow] (MSF)  -|  (Log) node [above,pos=0.25] {espectro} node [below,pos=0.25] {de Mel}   ;  
    \draw[arrow] (Log.south) |-  (DCT.east);  
    \draw [arrow] (DCT) -- (MFCC) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I didn´t really understood how to draw the lines but I think I am starting to. I appreciate that you didn´t just answered my question, but helped me better understand where they were coming from.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, in the third item of your comments I first time see described this features! I discover it accidentally in drawing one of my TikZ images, Is this features documented somewhere? If it is in TikZ manual, in spite to often reading it, I didn't see it.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, find the description of the `pos` key, it is mentioned there. (Section 17.8, bottom of page 235 in the version of the manual I have.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you for info! Just now I download recent version of manual (3.0.1a) and found this description (at bottom of page 235). I'm pretty sure, that in older one doesn't has  this information. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. for the answer!